# Flutter Project: Gradle Build Error - "Could not resolve com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.0"

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, gradle

[flutter_firebase_gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Do0.png)

This error seems to be connected to the Firebase plugin and might be impacting my Flutter project's build.

---

1. I've ensured that the correct version of the Firebase plugin is applied in my Flutter app's build.gradle file and the corresponding dependency is included in the project-level build.gradle file.
2. this is inside my android/app/build.gradle
   [image]
3. this is inside my android/build.gradle
   [image]

---

1. Does the version 4.4.0 of the com.google.gms.google-services plugin work with Flutter projects, or is there a different version I should use?
2. Are there any specific steps that I should follow to ensure the correct setup of Firebase in my Flutter project, in addition to configuring the Firebase plugin in the build.gradle files?
3. Is there anything unique to Flutter or any other considerations that I might be overlooking in my project configuration that could be contributing to this issue?

I would appreciate any guidance or recommendations to help resolve this Gradle build error in my Flutter project. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I resolved it Use this one inside android/build.gradle**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
```